# Why is "and" excluding any pairs (x,y) that have a 0 in them, rather than just excluding the one where both are 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python 3 code that looks something like this:

```
for x in range(-1,2): 
    for y in range(-1,2):
        if x != 0 and y != 0:
            print("True")
```

Output looks like this:

```
True
True
True
True
```

It's supposed to output 8 `"True"`s. One for each permutation that isn't `(0,0)`, when `x` and `y` both equal `0`. Why is it outputting 4 instead?

Further investigation with replacing `"print("True")"` with `"print(x,y)"` outputs:

```
-1,-1
1,-1
-1,1
1,1
```

Where did the `0`s go?

Comment: Because you literally said `if x is not equal to zero and y is not equal to zero`. What did you expect is called `OR` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "or"

```
for x in range(-1,2):
    for y in range(-1,2):
        if x != 0 or y != 0:
            print(x, y)
            print("True")
```